# Trying to run an ASP.NET MVC application using Mono on Apache with FastCGI

Tags: apache-2.2, asp.net, fastcgi, mono

I have a hosting account with DreamHost and I would like to use the same account to run ASP.NET applications. I have an application deployed in a subdomain, a .htaccess with a handler like this:

```
# Define the FastCGI Mono launcher as an Apache handler and let
# it manage this web-application (its files and subdirectories)
SetHandler monoWrapper
Action monoWrapper /home/arienh4/<domain>/cgi-bin/mono.fcgi virtual
```

My mono.fcgi is set up as such:

```
#!/bin/sh
#umask 0077
exec >>/home/arienh4/tmp/mono-fcgi.log
exec 2>>/home/arienh4/tmp/mono-fcgi.err

echo $(date +"[%F %T]") Starting fastcgi-mono-server2

cd /
chmod 0700 /home/arienh4/tmp/mono-fcgi.sock
echo $$>/home/arienh4/tmp/mono-fcgi.pid
# stdin is the socket handle
export PATH="/home/arienh4/mono/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/arienh4/mono/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export TMP="/home/arienh4/tmp"
export MONO_SHARED_DIR="/home/arienh4/tmp"
exec /home/arienh4/mono/bin/mono /home/arienh4/mono/lib/mono/2.0/fastcgi-mono-server2.exe \
/logfile=/home/arienh4/logs/fastcgi-mono-web.log /loglevels=All \
/applications=/:/home/arienh4/<domain>
```

I took this from the Mono site for CGI. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly though. This code is resulting in this error:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I have no idea what's causing this. As far as I can see, Mono isn't even hit (no log files are created).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any ModRewrite scripts running?  Usually an incorrect ModRewrite which causes an infinite loop would cause this.

You might want to turn on the mod_cgi "ScriptLog" directive which will log the execution of your CGI script.

Comment: There isn't any Rewrite. I'll try the log.
EDIT: Nope, doesn't seem to have had any effect, it doesn't log.